# Unpredictable behaviour while allocating memory in struct

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, struct, malloc

I am new at C and want to find out how memory allocation and pointers work. But I am struggled with some strange behaviour of my code. See the code and output below. I am using mingw, gcc version 4.9.2 (tdm-1), not sure is it a bug or I missing something? Is it correct way of sending structures to/from a function? And is it ok to simply assign staticly allocated array to a pointer? No warnings from gcc btw.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct S {

  int *a;

} s_t;

s_t
create_s () {
  s_t s;
  s.a = malloc ( sizeof ( int ) * 5 );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    s.a [ i ] = i << 1;
  }
  return s;
}

void
fill_s ( s_t s ) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    s.a [ i ] = i;
  }
}

void
kill_s ( s_t s ) {
  free ( s.a );
}

void
fill1_s_from_const ( s_t s ) {
  int array [ 5 ] = { 11, 21, 31, 41, 51 };
  s.a = array;
}

s_t
fill2_s_from_const () {
  int array [ 5 ] = { 12, 22, 32, 42, 52 };
  s_t s;
  s.a = array;
  return s;
}

void
copy_s_from_const ( s_t s ) {
  int array [ 5 ] = { 111, 222, 333, 444, 555 };
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    s.a [ i ] = array [ i ];
  }
}

int
main () {

  s_t s = create_s ();
  printf ( "\ncreate_s\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }

  fill_s ( s );
  printf ( "\nfill_s\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }

  copy_s_from_const ( s );
  printf ( "\ncopy_s_from_const\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }

  kill_s ( s );

  // not working at all (array filled with garbage)
  fill1_s_from_const ( s );
  printf ( "\nfill1_s_from_const\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }

  // works partly (array filled correctly but some fields are still full of garbage)
  s = fill2_s_from_const ();
  printf ( "\nfill2_s_from_const\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }

  // same as fill1_s_from_const or fill2_s_from_const (imo) but works perfectly fine
  int b [ 5 ] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 };
  s.a = b;
  printf ( "\ninline\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR10n.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on the "strange behavior". What is your expected output and what is the actual output? Also, please add the output directly into the question (as code), instead of only linking to an image. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void
fill1_s_from_const ( s_t s ) {
  int array [ 5 ] = { 11, 21, 31, 41, 51 };
  s.a = array;
}
```

Structs are passed by value, so this function doesn't do anything. After you call it, the caller's `s.a` is still what it was before, in your case a pointer to memory you just freed.

```
s_t
fill2_s_from_const () {
  int array [ 5 ] = { 12, 22, 32, 42, 52 };
  s_t s;
  s.a = array;
  return s;
}
```

Assigning an array to a pointer is by reference, so calling this function results in giving the caller a dangling pointer in `s.a`.

```
  // same as fill1_s_from_const or fill2_s_from_const (imo) but works perfectly fine
  int b [ 5 ] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 };
  s.a = b;
  printf ( "\ninline\n" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf ( "%d\n", s.a [ i ] );
  }
```

This works because unlike `fill2_s_from_const`, the pointer doesn't become dangling before you use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

fill_s works because I am sending s by value so s.a in fill_s has the same value (pointing to the same memory block) as s.a in main, while both s'es are separate structure instances.

fill1_s_from_const does not work the same way because I am assigning value to the local s.a created on function call, it is not the same as s.a in main (values are). Function will work as fill2_s_from_const if s will be passed as a pointer.

fill2_s_from_const simply sets to s.a the pointer to the local memory block. When program returns back to the main, the data stored in there is already destroyed (in my case -- partially, wich confuses me).

Sorry for the dumb question (cannot delete it).